# ckeditor showing html entities as plain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have used ckeditor with php but it is showing html entities such as line breaks and anchor tag as plain text. I have seen other links and made changes in the config of the ckeditor but it is not working.

```
Hello,<br>Please join me <a href='https://.........'>link</a>
```

> My config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; 
    config.language = 'es';
    config.uiColor = '#F7B42C';
    config.height = 300;
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.entities = true; 
    config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;

   };
  CKEDITOR.replace('email_content');
```

Comment: while entering or viewing after save the document?

Comment: While viewing i get html

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are displaying the value directly.If so instead of that use `@Html.Raw(value)` .

```
<textarea id="email_content" name="email_content">@Html.Raw(value)</textarea>
```